# Volume form on a disk and induced orientation 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm having trouble with this question:

Choose a volume form $\zeta$ on the disk $D(r) = \{(x,y,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq r^2\}$ and describe what the induced orientation 1-form looks like in the point $(r,0,0)$.

I tried to solve this, but end up with a volume form of $0$. This shouldn't happen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly did you do?

Comment: In my book it said $\zeta (v_1, ..., v_n) = det(v_1,N(p))$ with $N(p)$ the unit normal vectorfield and $v_1, ..., v_n$ an orthonormal basis for the tangent space to $D(r)$. I thought that the tangent space to $D(r)$ is a 2 -surface so I took $n = 2$ and $v_1 = (0,-1,0), v_2 = (-1,0,0)$ and $N(p) = (\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r},0)$. Calculating the determinant gives me $0$.

Comment: So by unit normal, it is normal to the surface $\{(x, y, 0)\}$. Your $N$ is still tangential to this surface.

Comment: In that case $N(p) = (0,0,1)$ should work. We have $(0,0,1) \cdot (x,y,0) = 0$. In that case we have a determinant of $-1$. What does this tell me about the induced orientation 1-form though?

Comment: In general, given a volume form $\omega$ on a surface $D$ with boundary $\partial D$, what is the induced orientation one form?

Comment: I really don't know. Intuitively I would say the sign of $\omega$.